# Flutter check if app was in memory when launched (How to check if splash screen is shown in iOS)

Tags: ios, dart, flutter

**Background**

For Android, things are pretty easy, when user uses back button, the app gets destroyed and when he taps home button the app is just stopped and it is still in the memory.

However in iOS, things become bit tricky. When I press Home button in an iOS app, chances are the app get terminated by the system (if it is not doing any background work) but when can it get terminated, that is unknown.

---

**Question**

Let's say I have splash screen, so if the app is not in the memory, then iOS system will show the splash screen, however if the app is already in memory, then the iOS system will take you directly to the app page. So, I wanna know how can we check if the app was in memory or not. I mean how can I check if splash screen is shown or not.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the state is `AppLifecycleState.resumed` when the app is launched and it was in memory.

So here is the solution:

```
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
    // app launched/reopened and was in memory
  }
}
```

Comment: If anyone has better answer, please provide me, I am happy to accept your answer. Thanks